# This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. in android google maps

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I got a poly line between two locations using google maps and when i want to get routes and directions between those two locations by using this URL using Json parsing
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=fromlocation&destination=destinationlocation&sensor=false&key=**********API KEY*********** 
it is getting the json parsing as 
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
I have got the authorized APIKEY using keytool and with package name and finger print key

here is the code what i have done thanks  in advance and  sorry for my english...

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DirectionActivity2.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    String URL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=start&destination=end&sensor=false&key=****API KEY*****";
ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

// Making a request to url and getting response
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();


}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update June 28 2019:**

Previously, google used to allow calling directions, geo-location api's without an api key up to a [certain extent](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/account-changes/?&sign=0#no-plan). It was a handy feature for development as you could just change the url in the browser. They have updated their policy.

Now you will need to provide a valid api key. More information in following [link](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/account-changes/?&sign=0).

**Previous Answer:**

Try removing the API key. I used this and it is returning me a valid json.

Comment: But why. Why cant we use it ?

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji probably because it is not a supported format of url.

Comment: no, it is giving error message - You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.

Comment: @debo.stackoverflow Updated answer. Previously, I could make api calls without the api key. Now I cannot.